# How can I ignore empty parameters in express application

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I have an api that requires some parameters to filter based on the the passed in parameter. It is similar top `localhost:8000/api/v1/products?page=1&user=62831ebc8cecf3c829c4b2d9&category=62831ebc8cecf3c829c4b2d9`

So I created a react action

```
export const listProducts =
  (page = '', user = '', category = '') =>
  async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST })

      const { data } = await axios.get(
        `${process.env.REACT_APP_API}/api/v1/products?&page=${page}&user=${user}&category=${category}`
      )

      dispatch({
        type: PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS,
        payload: data,
      })
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch({
        type: PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL,
        payload:
          error.response && error.response.data.message
            ? error.response.data.message
            : error.message,
      })
    }
  }
```

The Idea is that when I when I dispatch `dispatch(listProducts(1, user._id)` and I leave the 3rd parameter empty, It returns `Invalid category ''`

How can I make the api ignore unsent paramaters and only use sent parameters.

I have tried replacing   `(page = '', user = '', category = '')` with   `(page = null, user = null, category = null)`

Now i get `Invalid category null`

EDIT:  In some instances, i would want to pass only categories while in some other instances, I would want to pass user and page only. How can I do this `${process.env.REACT_APP_API}/api/v1/products?&page=${page}&user=${user}&category=${category}` to only accept data in the object and ignore what's not available

Comment: Are you OK with passing a single object as a parameter rather than passing multiple parameters?

Comment: @SinanYaman Can you write a pseudocode? In some instances, i would want to pass only categories while in some other instances, I would want to pass user and page only. How can I do this `${process.env.REACT_APP_API}/api/v1/products?&page=${page}&user=${user}&category=${category}` to only accept data in the object and ignore what's not available

Answer (score 0):

If the number of parameters passed to the function is frequently changing, or if you don't have control on what will be passed to the function I would achieve this by using a single object as a parameter rather than multiple parameters.

#### Example:

Instead of `export const listProducts = (page = '', user = '', category = '') =>` you can pass a single object and deconstruct the fields from the object like:

```
export const listProducts = ({page, user, category }) =>

//will be passed like:
listProducts({
 page: 1,
 user: data.user,
 category: ''
})
```

### Why?

You don't have to control the order of the parameters while passing arguments to the function and if a field is not passed to the function; it will evaluate to undefined:

```js
const obj1 = {
  page: 1,
  user: 'test',
  category: 'first'
}

const obj2 = {
  page: 2,
  user: 'test2'
}

const obj3 = {
  user: 'test3'
}

const listProducts = ({page, user, category}) => {
  const str = `Parameters:\n page: ${page}\nuser: ${user}\ncategory: ${category}`
  console.log(str)
}

listProducts(obj1)
listProducts(obj2)
listProducts(obj3)

console.log("\n-------------DEFAULT VALUES------\n")
/* Default value example: */
const listProducts2 = ({page = 1, user = '', category = ''}) => {
  const str = `Parameters:\n page: ${page}\nuser: ${user}\ncategory: ${category}`
  console.log(str)
}

listProducts2(obj1)
listProducts2(obj2)
listProducts2(obj3)
```

#### Ignoring undefined parameters (may not be efficient, just a try):

```
let url = `${process.env.REACT_APP_API}/api/v1/products?`
if(user) url += `&user=${user}`
if(page) url += `&page=${page}`
if(category) url += `&category=${category}`
```